# Excluding pages from dynamic content for posts set in functions.php - WP

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have successfully managed, with the help of someone extremely helpful here on stackoverflow, to add a a custom and dynamic description to all the posts used in my website. My issue now is that when opening one of my pages, I do not get the page content but the dynamic description that was intended for posts only.

The code I have added to my functions.php to generate the dynamic descriptions is as follows:

```
function add_after_post_content($content) {
global $post;
if(!is_feed() && !is_home() && is_singular() && is_main_query()) {
    $post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID );
    $cats = array();

    foreach($post_categories as $c){
        $cat = get_category( $c );
        $cats[] = array( 'name' => $cat->name, 'slug' => $cat->slug );
    }

    $content = '<h2>About the wallpaper:</h2><br />The <strong>'. $post->post_title . ' wallpaper</strong> is a high quality and high resolution wallpaper that has been posted in the <strong>';

        foreach($cats as $c){
           $content .= $c['name'];
        }

        $content .= '</strong> category by <strong>Free Wallpapers</strong> on '. $post->post_date . '.';
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_after_post_content');
```

The issue now is that I am finding on post pages eg. copyright page, that the dynamic content is being used instead of the content set in the wordpress admin.

```
Copyright Policy and Usage Rights
About the wallpaper:

The Copyright Policy and Usage Rights wallpaper is a high quality and high resolution wallpaper that has been posted in the category by Free Wallpapers on 2014-05-14 20:56:29.
```

I would like to continue using the dynamic content for my posts, while excluding pages from displaying it. Any help in regards to this matter would be greatly appreciate.

Best Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the [is_singular](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular) function. Now you want to define your content like this:

```
function add_after_post_content($content) {
    global $post;
    if(!is_feed() && !is_home() && is_singular('post') && is_main_query()) {
        $post_categories = wp_get_post_categories( $post->ID );
        $cats = array();

        foreach($post_categories as $c){
            $cat = get_category( $c );
            $cats[] = array( 'name' => $cat->name, 'slug' => $cat->slug );
        }

        $content = '<h2>About the wallpaper:</h2><br />The <strong>'. $post->post_title . ' wallpaper</strong> is a high quality and high resolution wallpaper that has been posted in the <strong>';

        foreach($cats as $c){
            $content .= $c['name'];
        }

        $content .= '</strong> category by <strong>Free Wallpapers</strong> on '. $post->post_date . '.';
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'add_after_post_content');
```

Comment: Hi, when trying that i get the following error on my site: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home4/awidaa/freewallpapers/wp-content/themes/whitewall/functions.php on line 1132

Comment: You didn't post the whole function and there was at least one `}` I was unable to account for. If you can edit your post with the full function I can get it fixed up.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. My original post has been modified to reflect the entire function. Best Regards

Comment: Updated the answer. You already has `is_singular`, you just needed it to check for post.

Comment: Absolutely beautiful, that worked perfectly. Thank you for your great help.

Comment: Not a problem. Please remember to accept the answer :)